# How to find the beta value from linear regression model?

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression

For the linear regression model,

```
  y_i = beta_0 + summation(x_i,j * beta_j )+ e_j
```

from the above equation, How I will find the value of beta(beta_0,beta_1...beta_j)?

Comment: See [the Estimation section in OLS on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Simple_regression_model).

Comment: yes, They have written for beta_0 and beta_1 ... then how I will find the value for beta_1,beta_2...?? @AmiTavory

Comment: If you augment your $X$ matrix by a column of 1s (to account for $\beta_0$), then you can get the entire vector of $\beta$ with the estimation $\frac{X^ty}{X^tX}$.

Comment: y_i = beta_0 * x_0+ summation(x_i,j * beta_j )+ e_j   ... you are saying like this, here if x_0 is a column vector of 1s then I will get all the values by doing X^ty/X^tX??@AmiTavory

Comment: Yes, that's the standard way of getting the coefficients in OLS.

Comment: @AmiTavory You shouldn't use a division line to denote matrix multiplication by an inverse.  Since matrix multiplication is not commutative, the meaning of your expression is ambiguous.

Comment: @MatthewDrury Thanks, you're right. That is an abuse of notation.

Comment: ok sir thanks both of you. I have one more doubt that if I add a penalty with regularization like lamda||beta||_1 (lass0) How it finding the sparse matrix??@AmiTavory

Comment: my question is that how estimated beta is becoming sparse after adding this penalty ??

Comment: @SudipDas If you add an l1 penalty, beta will tend to become sparse (under certain conditions), but the solution is not closed form. I suggest you read up on Elements Of Statistical Learning, which has a free online version at the authors' website.

Comment: okk sir @AmiTavory

Comment: @SudipDas No problem. All the best.